# Rails to excel with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'am new on rails , i've spent my day looking for solution to export my data into excel file.

I've tryed to_xls, simple_xlxs and other gems, also i've tryed to render xml template , but i've no success.

So i have **associations** between 2 models:

Call model:

```
class Call < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :number
  has_many :results
end
```

and my **result** model:

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :call
end
```

So i need to genrate excel tables with my OWN headers in table calle'd as i want. 
And also i wan't that in this excel file will be columns from my associeted model

What can i do?
Thanks

Comment: Can you add some details about what your _specific_ problem is?  For instance, your code that builds the excel file, the output and what you're expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# install in a gem file or in the terminal to test
# gem install spreadsheet


require 'spreadsheet'

Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'

book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
sheet1 = book.create_worksheet :name => 'test'

money_format = Spreadsheet::Format.new :number_format => "#,##0.00 [$€-407]"
date_format = Spreadsheet::Format.new :number_format => 'MM.DD.YYYY'

# set default column formats
sheet1.column(1).default_format = money_format
sheet1.column(2).default_format = date_format

# depending on your data you obviously have to create a loop that fits  the format of your data
sheet1.row(0).push "just text", 5.98, DateTime.now

book.write 'sample.xls'
```

The above code example writes the data to columns you create. You can have your info in csv style. So if you're returning objects you can just get values for each object and join the array with ',' separation and loop through.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your answer to provide some context on how this code example should be used, and how it will help to solve the problem.

Comment: Hi @fgc29, in that case, you should write what you just wrote as an edit to your question, instead of as a comment answer. You can always edit your own questions to do so.